# ntp offset can't be reduced

Tags: networking, server, ntp

we have a (windows) ntp server to witch we pull for time service. Connection en rights are oke. When we restart our virtual ubuntu 14.04 server the offset is within 20ms but after 60 sec the offset jumps to over 68000ms.
This is a bit of a problem (understatement) because its a postgres server.

result ntpq -cpe -cas

*remote        refid           st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter*

*10.100.100.4 185.51.192.34    3 u   26   64  377    0.684  69771.3 154.202*

*+10.100.100.5 10.100.100.4     4 u   29   64  377    0.659  69776.2 166.560*

*ind assid status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt*

*1 45921  961a   yes   yes  none  sys.peer    sys_peer  1*

*2 45922  942a   yes   yes  none candidate    sys_peer  2*

connection seems oke.
anyone any idea why the time keeps jumping back to the uge offset?
Or where i can search for the reason why this is happening

Comment: did a grep on the syslog after setting date -t manually:                                        
Feb  6 13:18:30  lsass: [lsass] Failed to sync system time [error code: 40075]
Feb  6 13:18:34  ntpd[7847]: 0.0.0.0 c61c 0c clock_step +69.895747 s
Feb  6 13:19:43  ntpd[7847]: 0.0.0.0 c614 04 freq_mode
Feb  6 13:19:44  ntpd[7847]: 0.0.0.0 c618 08 no_sys_peer

Comment: Please edit your question and format both the command output and the log messages correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible problems with your Ubuntu VM are:

1. You have time sync with the host enabled (this is common on VMware and Hyper-V systems) and it is interfering with NTP's ability to set the virtual system clock.
2. The host on which you are running your Ubuntu VM is under heavy load and/or has an inaccurate hardware clock.

Post your NTP configuration and we may be able to make further suggestions.